# React Query: how to sort data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-query

**My main component**

Here I'm fetching data from backend and receiving it well. Here how it looks like.

And now I want to sort them by their properties like step 1, step 2. I'm using React query to fetch data but I'm not sure how to sort it. Also, I already have sorting functions. But, I don't know how to change data based on the sorting atribute.

[image].

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useFetchTable from "../../../../api/table/useFetchTable";

const TableList = () => {
  const { data: response, status, isLoading } = useFetchTable();
  // const [sortField, setSortField] = useState("");
  // const [order, setOrder] = useState("asc");

  // const handleSortingChange = (accessor) => {
  //   const sortOrder =
  //     accessor === sortField && order === "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";
  //   setSortField(accessor);
  //   setOrder(sortOrder);
  //   handleSorting(accessor, sortOrder);
  // };

  // const handleSorting = (sortField, sortOrder) => {
  //   if (sortField) {
  //     const sorted = [...data].sort((a, b) => {
  //       if (a[sortField] === null) return 1;
  //       if (b[sortField] === null) return -1;
  //       if (a[sortField] === null && b[sortField] === null) return 0;
  //       return (
  //         a[sortField].toString().localeCompare(b[sortField].toString(), "en", {
  //           numeric: true,
  //         }) * (sortOrder === "asc" ? 1 : -1)
  //       );
  //     });
  //     setData(sorted);
  //   }
  // };


  if (status === "error") {
    return "Error";
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  console.log(response);

  const Print = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <span className="text-xs bg-blue-100 rounded-full px-2 py-0.5 ml-2">
        {children}%
      </span>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead className="border-b-2">
          <tr>
            <th className="py-1">Product Name</th>
            <th>Purchases</th>
            <th>US</th>
            <th>Ch Step 1</th>
            <th>Ch Step 2</th>
            <th>CVR</th>
            <th> 1</th>
            <th>Upsell 2</th>
            <th>Upsell 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {response.data?.map((row, idx) => (
            <tr key={idx}>
              <td>{row.name}</td>
              <td>
                {row.purchases[0]} <Print>{row.purchases[1]}</Print>
              </td>
              <td>
                {row.unique_sessions} <Print>100</Print>
              </td>
              <td>
                {row.checkout_step_1[0]} <Print>{row.checkout_step_1[1]}</Print>
              </td>

              <td>
                {row.checkout_step_2[0]} <Print>{row.checkout_step_2[1]}</Print>
              </td>

              <td>
                <Print>{`${row["cvr_%"]}`}</Print>
              </td>
              <td>
                {row.upsell_1_takes[0]} <Print>{row.upsell_1_takes[1]}</Print>
              </td>

              <td>
                {row.upsell_2_takes[0]} <Print>{row.upsell_2_takes[1]}</Print>
              </td>

              <td>
                {row.upsell_3_takes[0]} <Print>{row.upsell_3_takes[1]}</Print>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      TableList
      {/* {data?.map((el) => {
        el.title;
      })} */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TableList;
```

Comment: it looks like the following link will solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797655/filtering-a-fetched-list-from-an-api-using-react-query

Comment: No it's not. Its just filtering to get data. But I need to sort it

Answer (score 0):

So for sorting based on your column header you can create a function to handle that onClick of the particular header. Like in the below code I have used the `firstName` column for sorting. On clicking the first name header it will trigger the function `sortByFirstName` and added the sort functionality in it and updated the state of the `setTableData` . Hope this helps.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import './style.css'

function Example () {
   const [sorted, setSorted] = useState({ sorted: "fname", reversed: false });
   const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])


   const { data } = useQuery({
      queryKey: ['repoData'],
      queryFn: () =>
         fetch('https://dummyjson.com/users?limit=10').then(
            (res) => res.json(),
         ),
   })



   useEffect(() => {
      if (data) {
         setTableData(data?.users)
      }

   }, [data])

   const sortByFirstName = () => {
      setSorted({ sorted: "fname", reversed: !sorted.reversed })
      const tableDataCopy = [...tableData];
      tableDataCopy.sort((a, b) => {
         let fnameA = a.firstName.toLowerCase();
         let fnameB = b.firstName.toLowerCase();

         if (sorted.reversed) {
            return fnameB.localeCompare(fnameA)
         }

         return fnameA.localeCompare(fnameB)
      })
      setTableData(tableDataCopy)
   }

   return (
      <div className='h-full w-full'>

         <table className='data' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
               <tr>
                  <th onClick={ sortByFirstName }>First Name</th>
                  <th >Last Name</th>
                  <th >Gender</th>
                  <th >Email</th>
                  <th >Bloodgroup</th>
                  <th >Age</th>
                  <th > Weight</th>
                  <th >Maiden Name</th>
                  <th >Phone</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               { tableData?.map((row, idx) => (
                  <tr key={ idx }>
                     <td>{ row.firstName }</td>
                     <td>
                        { row.lastName }
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        { row.gender }
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        { row.email }
                     </td>

                     <td>
                        { row.bloodGroup }
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        { row.age }
                     </td>

                     <td>
                        { row.weight }
                     </td>

                     <td>
                        { row.maidenName }
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        { row.phone }
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               )) }
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>


   )
}

export default Example
```